# Check if a value is present in scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope called `$scope.activities`. Inside that scope are multiple objects. Each object has a string called `viewed` with the value of `check` or `uncheck`. I would like to check if the value `uncheck` is present in the scope.

I've created this, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
if (activities.indexOf("uncheck") == -1) {
  console.log ('uncheck found')
  $scope.newActivities = 'newActivities';
} else {
  console.log ('no uncheck found')
}
```

Because in `activities` I have two objects, one with the `uncheck` value, and a object without it.

```
[{"id":2,", "viewed":"check"}, {"id":3,", "viewed":"uncheck"}]
```

Comment: If you have `activities` array inside your `scope`, you must fix your `if` condition with: `if ($scope.activities.indexIf("uncheck") == -1) {...}`. Perhaps this will fix your code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to loop each object and check the property - you can use `Array.some`

```
var hasValue = activities.some(function(obj) { return obj.viewed == "unchecked" });
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop over each object in the array and test if the property "viewed" equal to "unchek"

```
var activities  = [{"id":2, "viewed":"check"}, {"id":3, "viewed":"uncheck"}];
var activities2  = [{"id":2, "viewed":"check"}, {"id":3, "viewed":"check"}];
var check = function(data){
    var checked = false;
    for(var i in data){
        if(data[i].hasOwnProperty("viewed") && (data[i]["viewed"]=="uncheck") ){
            checked = true ;
        }
    }
    return checked;
} ;

console.log(check(activities));
console.log(check(activities2));
```

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the code. It seems that the code is looking at the last item. `var activities  = [{"id":2, "viewed":"check"}, {"id":3, "viewed":"uncheck"}];` this returns true. And this `var activities  = [{"id":2, "viewed":"uncheck"}, {"id":3, "viewed":"check"}];` returns false. While the array has the same content.